# Spring cloud aws stream, messages are consumed by multiple instances in consumer group

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I have written a sample application with spring cloud aws binder

```
  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kinesis:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')
```

**Code**

```
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
public void receive(Message<String> message) {      
    System.out.println("Message recieved: "+message);
    System.out.println("Message Payload: "+message.getPayload());    

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input: 
          group: group
          destination: stream
          content-type: application/json          
        output:  
          group: group
          destination: stream
          content-type: application/json
```

I have started the application on multiple ports

```
8081,8082,8083, 8084.
```

When I publish the message to stream, most of the times more than one instance is consuming message.

For example I sent message {"22":"11"}, this has been consumed by both 8083 and 8084

**message on application:8084**

```
2018-03-16 12:29:19.715  INFO 10084 --- [           main] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter{shardOffsets=[KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=TRIM_HORIZON, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='stream', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}], consumerGroup='group'}
2018-03-16 12:29:19.809  INFO 10084 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8084 (http) with context path ''
2018-03-16 12:29:19.809  INFO 10084 --- [           main] com.example.aws.AwsApplication           : Started AwsApplication in 21.034 seconds (JVM running for 22.975)
2018-03-16 12:29:19.840  INFO 10084 --- [esis-consumer-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : The [ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=TRIM_HORIZON, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='stream', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}, state=NEW}] has been started.
2018-03-16 12:30:23.929  INFO 10084 --- [esis-consumer-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : The records '[{SequenceNumber: 49582549849562056887358041088912873574803531055853731842,ApproximateArrivalTimestamp: Fri Mar 16 12:30:21 IST 2018,Data: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=47 cap=47],PartitionKey: partitionKey-0,}]' are skipped from processing because their sequence numbers are less than already checkpointed: 49582549849562056887358041088912873574803531055853731842
Message recieved: GenericMessage [payload={"22":"11"}, headers={aws_shard=shardId-000000000000, id=f6cb4b6d-e149-059f-7e4d-aa9dfeeef10e, contentType=application/json, aws_receivedStream=stream, aws_receivedPartitionKey=partitionKey-0, aws_receivedSequenceNumber=49582549849562056887358041088914082500623155992949948418, timestamp=1521183774995}]
Message Payload: {"22":"11"}
```

**message on application:8083**

```
018-03-16 12:29:05.733  INFO 8188 --- [           main] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter{shardOffsets=[KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=TRIM_HORIZON, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='stream', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}], consumerGroup='group'}
2018-03-16 12:29:05.733  INFO 8188 --- [esis-consumer-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : The [ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=TRIM_HORIZON, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='stream', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}, state=NEW}] has been started.
2018-03-16 12:29:05.796  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8083 (http) with context path ''
2018-03-16 12:29:05.796  INFO 8188 --- [           main] com.example.aws.AwsApplication           : Started AwsApplication in 19.463 seconds (JVM running for 20.956)
Message recieved: GenericMessage [payload={"22":"11"}, headers={aws_shard=shardId-000000000000, id=cf8647fe-8ce5-70b5-eeb9-74a08efc870a, contentType=application/json, aws_receivedStream=stream, aws_receivedPartitionKey=partitionKey-0, aws_receivedSequenceNumber=49582549849562056887358041088914082500623155992949948418, timestamp=1521183775155}]
Message Payload: {"22":"11"}
```

Ideally only one consumer in group shall handle message. Am I missing something here.

Comment: Do you use `DynamoDbMetaDataStore` for checkpointing? Any chance to have a simple application on GH and instruction how to reproduce? Thanks

Comment: @ ArtemBilan Thank you for looking into this. We do not use any special DynamoDbMetaDataStore explicitly. I have same code that I had in my question. I can put sample project on github

Comment: Right, please. And also an instruction how to reproduce

Comment: @ArtemBilan. I have uploaded sample project here.  Can you check. https://github.com/patan12/spring-aws-cloud-poc

Comment: Thank you for the sample! I will come back to you later with some feedback. If not, ping me tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for validation the solution!

I think I found where is the problem. It is in the `ShardCheckpointer.checkpoint(String sequenceNumber)`.

The current code is like this:

```
if (existingSequence == null ||
        new BigInteger(existingSequence).compareTo(new BigInteger(sequenceNumber)) < 0) {
        this.checkpointStore.put(this.key, sequenceNumber);
        return true;
}
```

Where there is a race condition, when both (all?) nodes check the state and get a smaller value from the store. So, we are passing condition and then we all go to the `checkpointStore.put()` part. And here all of them stores a new the same value and return `true` to let the Channel Adapter to process the same record.

My fix for this is like:

```
       if (existingSequence == null ||
                new BigInteger(existingSequence).compareTo(new BigInteger(sequenceNumber)) < 0) {
            if (existingSequence != null) {
                return this.checkpointStore.replace(this.key, existingSequence, sequenceNumber);
            }
            else {
                this.checkpointStore.put(this.key, sequenceNumber);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

The same condition, but I also use `checkpointStore.replace()` with this contract:

```
/**
 * Atomically replace the value for the key in the store if the old
 * value matches the oldValue argument.
```

Right now I try to come up with the test-case to validate and will let you know when `BUILD-SNAPSHOT` is ready to consume and validate on your side.

Comment: OK! The fix has been reached the `/libs-snapshot`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/commit/2b57f34801df625587438536c66e994524899b4f

Comment: Thank you Artem Bilan. Appreciate the quick response. I shall validate and let you know

Comment: Would you mind to share your feedback about that fix? We might just release `M2` on the matter to give everybody a gain of the fix and so on. Thanks

Comment: I have tested this. I sent 100 messages in loop. I had 7 consumers running on same group. Three consumers got 66, 33 and 1 message respectively. The rest four did not get any message. The good part is that no duplicate messages across consumers. I have one question. Here we can see that one consumer got all most 66 messages. In real time, are there any chances that few consumers are overloaded?

Comment: Not sure what is the question, but that is absolutely fine that some consumers in the same group are in idle. They will pick up work when others will go. In the ideal world only one consumer in group should read from one shard, but that is the task for the future: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/66

Comment: Thank you Artem Bilan. Will this fix  be part of M2

Comment: Correct. I’m waiting now for feedback on some other performance issue and then release it. Btw maybe you can say anything there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/87 ?

Comment: I checked here. I did not try out kcl earlier. So, I cannot comment. But I did not find any delay in receiving messages

Comment: Good. Thanks! Would you mind to comment about your experience in that issue?